# Ultra low-latency YouTube broadcast using API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, low-latency, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is it already possible somehow to set up an YouTube Live broadcast with [Ultra low-latency](https://youtube-creators.googleblog.com/2017/09/youtube-live-faster-easier-and-more.html) settings enabled using API?

I cannot find any suitable option in [reference handbook](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts) nor examining the details of broadcast started by *Creator studio*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option finally added to [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#properties).

Ultra low-latency broadcast can be started using property **contentDetails.latencyPreference** and value **ultraLow**